# How to hide images with JQuery right after their loading which have a certain dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, onload

I would like to place a short JQuery code snippet on a webpage, which webpage contains thumbnail images. Sometimes thumbnail images get deleted for some reason from their server, and in this case linking to the non-existing images causes that an error message is served from the image hoster instead of the thumbnail picture, which is also an image, but contains an error text, rendered onto the small picture and that image always has a well defined known resolution, which never alters, eg.: width=177, height=142.

My attempt to achieve the hiding of the unneeded images which contains the error message, and works on "live" images too, which are created on the webpage automatically by DOM manipulaion, javascript, JQuery, pagination, etc:

```
$(document).on('load', 'img', function() { 
           if (($(this).width()==177) && ($(this).height())==142) {
                $(this).hide()
           };})
```

For some reason this doesn't work at all, images aren't hided. However when I apply this instead of the previous:

```
$(document).on('click', 'img', function() { 
           if (($(this).width()==177) && ($(this).height())==142) {
                $(this).hide()
           };
           return(false);})
```

Then it works, the images with the appropriate resolutions are hided when I click on them, and the event handler are attached to the "live" images too which are created by the  built-in javascript mechanism of the webpage by DOM manipulation, what serves as pagination. Pagination on the webpage is implemented with changing a content of a div element, not by full page load / reload. I am using JQuery 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the event to each image, not to the `document`:

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
       var image = $(this);
       if (image.width() == 177 && image.height() == 142) {
            image.hide();
       };
});
```

For runtime created images, you can do the following:

```
// Create a reusable function to eval each image
function evalImage(image) {
    if (image.width() == 177 && image.height() == 142) {
        image.hide();
    }
}

// Create a reusable function to hook to image load
function checkOnLoad(image, source) {
    image.load(function() {
        evalImage($(this));
    });
    newimage.attr('src', source);
}

// Eval images on first load
$('img').on('load', function() {
    evalImage($(this));
});

// Create a new image and eval when loaded
var newimage = $('<img />');
checkOnLoad(image, 'path/to/source.jpg');
```

Comment: Only problem is, that this approach don't work on the images which are created by DOM manipulation, after this code had run.

Comment: Check the approach for runtime created images. @Konstantin

Comment: I see, but I wouldn't like to modify the code section which creates the "live" images by DOM manipulation. Do I undesrtand well that I should add the later code to that section where "live" images are created by the webpage built-in mechanism?

Comment: Yes, you could also create a reusable function to achieve so.

Comment: @Konstantin check my modified snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery documentation metions that this method has caveats, see  https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Try following, but I am not sure whether it will work with dynamically added images:

```
$( "img" ).load(function() {
       if (($(this).width()==177) && ($(this).height())==142) {
            $(this).hide()
       };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check your imgs every time when you change your document.

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $("img:visible").each(function() {
        if(($(this).width()==177) && ($(this).height())==142) {
            $(this).hide()
        };
    });
});
```